# jquery - how could I bind the same things to 2 diffrent classes?

Tags: jquery

I have got:

```
$('.class1').click(function(){   //do
things on $(this) element })
```

and

```
$('.class2').click(function(){
  //do things on $(this) element
})
```

things to do in each of that is the same, but when I did:

```
$('.class2').click(function(){
   $('.class1').click();
})
```

... it was disaster, that actived each element with `class1`.
Is there any similar solution to above one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".class1,.class2").click(function(){ });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.class1, .class2').click(function(){   
  //do things on $(this) element 
}) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the multiple selector is the best way here. However in some situations, you have to bind the handlers dynamically. Use named functions then:

```
function handler() {
    // something
}

$('.class1').click(handler);
$('.class2').click(handler);
```

Comment: is inside handler still variable `this` to use?

Comment: @josh: Yes, `this` will always refer to the DOM element the handler is attached to.